# Can an ally kill a creep tumor?

Tags: starcraft-2

I was playing multiplayer and someone on my team was creeping over expansions, i tried to kill his creep tumor but couldnt. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, but you have to issue an explicit "Attack" order, just like when you would want to attack one of your own units/buildings.

If you have units selected and right click on the tumor, the units will just move there. If you instead hit `A` and then left-click on the tumor, they will attack it.

Comment: I thought that they made it so you couldn't attack allied units or buildings as an anti-griefing measure. Am I just imagining that?

Comment: @Raven yes, your imagining it

Comment: Damn. Too much League of Legends, I guess.

Comment: @raven: Playing next to a zerg can seriously suck if you're not zerg. I've definitely killed a few tumors in my time.

Comment: @Satanic As a zerg I have occasionally managed to block one of my own expos with a tumor...as in the tumor itself is physically in the way of where the hatch needs to go.

Comment: @enigmatic: Heh. Hoist upon your own petard.